# Pass user input from Excel to the prediction model in Python

Tags: python, excel, linear-regression, user-input

I've trained a linear regression model to predict income.

```
# features: 'Gender', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'HoursWorkedPerWeek', 'EducationLevel', 'EducationYears', 'Region', 'Race'

person_1_income = model.predict([[1, 47, 8, 40, 2, 13, 1, 1]])
print(person_1_income)
```

I am including quite a few features and I would like to make the process of inputting the values more user-friendly.
Is there a way to pass user inputs to the prediction model in a more efficient way? Ideally, **input the values in Excel** and pass them to the prediction model.